# clickable String in TextView into EditText insinde Adapter.class

Tags: java, android, watson-assistant

I am trying to set up an Chat, which communicates with IBM Watson Assistant. The Assistant has a function called `Options`. I implemented the functionality of these objects inside my `ChatApdater` and now I want to make my options clickable, **so whenever I click an option it shows up in my EditText field**, where you normally write your questions. Example [with 4 options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP06S.png)

My code of my `ChatApdater` looks like this:

```
protected Activity activity;
private int SELF = 100;
private ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;


public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList) {
    this.messageArrayList = messageArrayList;

}



@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;

    // view type is to identify where to render the chat message
    // left or right
    if (viewType == SELF) {
        // self message
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.chat_item_self, parent, false);
    } else {
        // WatBot message
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.chat_item_watson, parent, false);
    }


    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
    if (message.getId() != null && message.getId().equals("1")) {
        return SELF;
    }

    return position;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
    switch (message.type) {
        case TEXT:
            ((ViewHolder) holder).message.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.getMessage()+"<br/>"));
                break;
        case IMAGE:
            ((ViewHolder) holder).message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ImageView iv = ((ViewHolder) holder).image;
            Glide
                    .with(iv.getContext())
                    .load(message.getUrl())
                    .into(iv);
            break;
        case OPTION:
            TextView tv = ((ViewHolder) holder).message;
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            LinearLayout optionsContainer = ((ViewHolder) holder).optionsContainer;
            TextView messageTextView = createStartView(message.getMessage(), optionsContainer.getContext());
            optionsContainer.addView(messageTextView);

            for ( DialogNodeOutputOptionsElement r : message.getOptions() ) {
                System.out.println("blblba");
                String option = r.getLabel();
                TextView optionTextView = createTextView(option, optionsContainer.getContext());
                // add the created textView to our container
                optionsContainer.addView(optionTextView);
            }
            break;
        case PAUSE:break;
    }



}
private TextView createTextView(final String text, final Context context) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            ((int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setTextSize((float) 15);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    int blueColor = Color.parseColor("#0000ff");
    // make text blue
    tv.setTextColor(blueColor);
    // make text underline
    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //  Toast.makeText(context, "Link clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // add here what the click should do
        }

    });
    return tv;

}
private TextView createStartView(String text, Context context) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            ((int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setTextSize((float) 15);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    int blueColor = Color.parseColor("#0000ff");
    // make text blue

    // make text underline
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //  Toast.makeText(context, "Link clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // add here what the click should do
        }

    });
    return tv;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageArrayList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView message;
    ImageView image;
    LinearLayout optionsContainer;
    EditText eingabe;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        optionsContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionsContainer);
        eingabe = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.einmessage);








        //TODO: Uncomment this if you want to use a custom Font
        
    }
}
}
```

While the important part is right here:

```
 private TextView createTextView(final String text, final Context context) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            ((int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setTextSize((float) 15);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    int blueColor = Color.parseColor("#0000ff");
    // make text blue
    tv.setTextColor(blueColor);
    // make text underline
    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // STORE CLICKED OPTION IN EDITTEXT
        }

    });
    return tv;

}
```

I had to make 3 different XMLs for my chat. One for watson, myinput and the chat in total (where the Edittext is stored). This XML is not mentioned in the `ChatApdater` yet.

The XML looks like this:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/einmessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/what_s_on_your_mind"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the clicked item from `TextView` :

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {    
            String str = tv.getText().toString();     
}
```

To set the string in `EditText` :

```
View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0);
EditText editText = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.edit_text); //pass the id of your EditText here
editText.setText(str);
```

Comment: already tried this. But i does not let me do this, because I am wokring in an adapter, like I said. I shows me "Cannot resolve method findviewbyid"

Comment: findViewById should be called on a View, so fetch the current view from your RecyclerView and use it to fetch EditText. Edit the answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: no sadly it does not work like this, I already tried it. I used my Recyclerview which I used before. I think it does not work becuase I am using 3 different XML classes.